# Clicking on disabled 'add to cart' button

Tags: jquery, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a button in Woocommerce, which is to add to the cart.
It will sensibly only add to the cart if the relevant options have already been chosen. Until then, the button is disabled:

```
<button class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" type="submit"
    disabled="disabled" 
    title="Select product options before adding this product to your cart."
    >Add to cart</button>
```

By default - nothing happens when one clicks on the `button`, because it's disabled, but it might be confusing to a user seen as there is no feedback.

What I want to do, is have the `title` popup as an alert when this happens.

I have tried the following jQuery function, added in on the custom script option of the theme:

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";
  jQuery("button.single_add_to_cart_button[type=submit]").click(function(){
    var isDisabled = jQuery(this).is(':disabled');
    if (isDisabled){
      alert(jQuery("button.single_add_to_cart_button[type=submit]").attr('title'));
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

But nothing is triggered and there is no alert. I have also tried replacing the `jQuery` with `$`, but that doesn't work.

**UPDATE**
also tried this:

```
  jQuery(".variations_button").on("button.single_add_to_cart_button[type=submit]","click", function(){
        var isDisabled = jQuery(this).is(':disabled');
    if (isDisabled){
      alert(jQuery("button.single_add_to_cart_button[type=submit]").attr('title'));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Disabled elements don't fire mouse events, so you have to wrap a div around the button and catch the event.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. But even if I use the `div` around it, the event is on the [disabled] `button` itself - so how do I track the event?

Comment: Added another attempt in the question.